# Best way to include attachments using EmailService [Craft Plugin]?

Tags: plugin-development

I've got Email Service working correctly (http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/apis/emailservice) but what's the best way to include attachments when using this service?

Here's what I've got so far:

```
    $email = new EmailModel();
    $email->subject = "Thanks!";
    $email->htmlBody = "<h1>Congratulations!</h1";
    $email->htmlBody .= "<p>Hello World</p>";
    $email->fromEmail = "email@domain.com";
```

I see there is **$email->addAttachment** but I'm not sure what variables to include to make it pass through the service.

Anyone have any examples?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Contact Form](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ContactForm/blob/master/contactform/services/ContactFormService.php#L51) plugin has an example of doing this.

```
$email->addAttachment($message->attachment->getTempName(), $message->attachment->getName(), 'base64', $message->attachment->getType());
```

The `EmailModel->addAttachment()` signature looks like this:

```
* @param string $path Path to the attachment.
* @param string $name Overrides the attachment name.
* @param string $encoding File encoding (see $Encoding).
* @param string $type File extension (MIME) type.
```

Which is just a thin wrapper for [PHPMailer's addAttachment](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L2047) method.

Comment: I'm using $asset_url = craft()->assets->getUrlForFile($asset); and then $email->addAttachment = array($asset_url, 'plugin_name', 'base64', 'application/zip'); but it returns "Property "Craft\EmailModel.addAttachment" is not defined."

Comment: addAttachment is a method.  use $email->addAttachment($asset_url, 'plugin_name', 'base64', 'application/zip');

Comment: Once I change to $email->addAttachment() the entire function dies. If I remove it, it works. I'll send you a support note.

Answer (score 5):

In `craft/app/models/EmailModel.php` the function docblock describes the params:

```
/**
 * Adds an attachment from a path on the filesystem. Returns false if the file could not be found or accessed.
 *
 * @param string $path Path to the attachment.
 * @param string $name Overrides the attachment name.
 * @param string $encoding File encoding (see $Encoding).
 * @param string $type File extension (MIME) type.
 * @throws phpmailerException
 * @return bool
 */
public function addAttachment($path, $name = '', $encoding = 'base64', $type = 'application/octet-stream')
{
    $existingAttachments = $this->attachments;
    $existingAttachments[] = array('path' => $path, 'name' => $name, 'encoding' => $encoding, 'type' => $type);
    $this->attachments = $existingAttachments;
}
```

Is that what you're looking for?